# How to add gitlab private repository in Argocd

Tags: argocd

I am facing one issue let's assume I have created a GitLab repository and added in argocd using CRD with my username and password, how will other developers access or create a project or an application using that repo or please suggest how can we solve this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

It is better to setup SSH access then with username and password. Then it can be managed through keys.